# NTFS permissions set up in GPM overwrites current permissions

Tags: active-directory, permissions, group-policy

I'm trying to implement a policy in our current environment where NTFS permissions are added to the local drives. I've implemented this by editing the settings in Computer Configuration - Windows Settings - Security Settings - File System. Unfortunately, when I set up the settings, all of the current settings are overwritten when the GPO is applied. I've selected "Propagate inheritable permissions to all subfolders...", but all current permissions are removed and replaced by the settings in the GPO.

The screenshot below shows the current computer configuration settings within the GPO. http://pasteboard.co/yMjM5f5.jpg

Any idea on the correct implementation I need to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0
down vote
accept

For anyone that comes around this thread and faces the same issues, I've implemented a workaround by using a powershell startup script that adds the permissions. That seemed to do the trick. I've used the following script:

$C = (Get-Item "C:\").GetAccessControl('Access') $D = (Get-Item "D:\").GetAccessControl('Access') $Exec = New-Object system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule("MYDOMAIN\Dir_Local_Drives_R", "readandexecute", "Containerinherit,Objectinherit", "None", "Allow") $Deny = New-Object system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule("MYDOMAIN\Dir_Local_Drives_R", "write", "Containerinherit,Objectinherit", "None", "Deny")

$C.SetAccessRule($Exec) $C.SetAccessRule($Deny) Set-ACL "C:\" $C

$D.SetAccessRule($Exec) $D.SetAccessRule($Deny) Set-ACL "D:\" $D